# How to connect to ACR122 with CardService

Tags: java, acr122

I'm writing a program (Java Application) for reading ePassport. For access I use the library org.jmrtd. What kind of object should I transfer in CardService.getInstance() ?

```
import net.sf.scuba.smartcards.CardService;
import net.sf.scuba.smartcards.CardServiceException;
import org.jmrtd.BACKeySpec;
import org.jmrtd.PassportService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class TestComponent {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApp.class);

    public static void main(String args[])  {

        try {
            CardService cs = CardService.getInstance(???????);
            PassportService ps = new PassportService(cs);
            ps.open();
            ps.sendSelectApplet(false);

            ps.sendSelectApplet(false);
            BACKeySpec bacKey = new BACKeySpec() {
                public String getDocumentNumber() {
                    return "xxxxxxxx";
                }
                public String getDateOfBirth() {
                    return "yyMMdd";
                }
                public String getDateOfExpiry() {
                    return "yyMMdd";
                }
            };
            ps.doBAC(bacKey);
            ps.close();

        } catch (CardServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer found:

1. add in pom

   net.sf.scuba
           scuba-sc-j2se
           0.0.13
2. import net.sf.scuba.smartcards.TerminalCardService;
3. `CardTerminal terminal =TerminalFactory.getDefault().terminals().list().get(0);
           CardService cs = CardService.getInstance(terminal);
           PassportService ps = new PassportService(cs);
           ps.open();`